# Android screenshot in headless mode is ugly

Tags: android, image, android-emulator, screenshot, headless

I want to take screenshots of Android device in headless mode, that is to say I create it like this:

```
echo no | /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd \ 
         -n test01 -t android-17 -f -p some/dir -c 128 --abi x86
```

and then I start it like

```
/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd test01 -no-skin \
-no-audio -no-window -memory 256 -nocache -no-snapshot-save -no-snapstorage
```

I am taking screens like this:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
```

However that screenshot looks like this:

[image: taken screenshot is ugly]

Two questions:

1) How do I get rid of that "make yourself home" welcome crap? I am in headless mode so I can't click on that "ok" button at all.

2) How do I specify screensize to start emulator with? It seems it is somehow deformed and I do not know how and why. I bet it will be some bad configuration of startup parameters.

More critical for me is the first question, the second one is tweakable via some switches on command line upon execution of that emulator.

Thank you a lot

*UPDATE*

So I tried to take screenshots after application is running, I am using just some testing application which does not do anything at all actually, you just click around and fills some text areas, so ... I am taking screenshots after it is installed (it is logical since I am taking screenshots of that application) but dimensions of the screen are not changed, it looks like this:

[image: deformed application size]

I would be safisfied just with taking these screenshots in headless mode and the application is not deformed. How to do that geeez ...

Comment: The first problem, I would try to solve using a snapshot of the os (that I had first saved manually). Is there a reason you can't do that? Otherwise, I would think this "Make yourself at home message" is some kind of Activity that's launched by a Broadcast Receiver after boot up. Hopefully, the priority of its Broadcast Receiver is not set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for hints, 2 points, what do you mean by "hopefully the priority of its broadcast receiver is not set to 1" and how that fact helps me? The second one, I would like to avoid snapshots as much as possible since I am doing headless functional testing when I start my emulator dynamically on demand so I can't use some in-advance tweaked image to get rid of it. I need to use raw images generated by `android` Is it somehow possible to kill it externally,like `adb shell kill_that_welcome`? btw, it is such big deal? If I install and start some native app,it should overlay the welcome screen,no?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still hitting this issue, using '-no-window' but not '-no-skin' makes the screenshot dimensions look nicer.

Comment: Removing `--no-skin` helps improve the size of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for getting the proper screen resolution,
"echo qemu.sf.lcd_density=120 >> /system/build.prop"

You should have root permissions!!!

Answer (score 0):

As to #1 like you said, if you automatically install and launch your own app afterward, the Activity lifecycle will just behave as it is supposed to, and the first Activity will just disappear.

And even if there were an adb kill command, you would only be interfering with the normal way Android behaves, and that would only differentiate your testing environment from the environment your application will run in (which doesn't serve your purpose in any way).

As to issue #2, without doing any tweaks, try taking a screenshot after your application has already launched. I have a feeling this special overlay screen might have been what messed up the display in the first place.

Comment: Plese review my updated question. Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying -s "1080x1920" in the create avd command fixed this issue for me. The full command I am using:

```
echo "no" | android create avd --force --device "Nexus 5" --name test --target android-22 --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a -s "1080x1920" --sdcard 512M
```